# Optimizing Tensorflow for many small matrix-vector multiplications

Tags: tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

To build up a capsule network training script, I need to compute many small matrix-vector multiplications.
The size of each weight matrix is at most 20 by 20.
The number of weight matrices is more more than 900.

I'm curious `tf.matmul` or `tf.linalg.matvec` is the best option for this.
Could anybody give me a hint to optimize the training script?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the operations you want to perform? are these multiplications independent from each other? are they sequential? (each one depends on the results of the previous). What algorithm are you using? Could you outline your entire algorithm?

Comment: The algorithm is very similar to procedure 1 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.09829v2.pdf. the specific operation is u_hat_ij = W_ij * ui. each u_hat_ij is independent from each other.

Comment: If I understand correctly I think that is just a broadcasted element-wise multiplication? If you have your matrices in a 3D tensor `w` with shape `(900, 20, 20)` and your vectors in a 2D tensor `u` with shape `(900, 20)`, I think you just need `u_hat = w * tf.expand_dims(u, axis=2)` (would give you a 3D tensor with shape `(900, 20, 20)`).

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking about @jdehesa ! you should write it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Looking at the [notebook](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/extra_capsnets.ipynb) that you are referring to, it seems you have the following parameters:

```py
batch_size = 50
caps1_n_caps = 1152
caps1_n_dims = 8
caps2_n_caps = 10
caps2_n_dims = 16
```

And then you have a tensor `w` with shape `(caps1_n_caps, caps2_n_caps, caps2_n_dims, caps1_n_dims)` (in the notebook it has an initial dimension with size `1` that I am skipping) and another tensor `caps1_output` with shape `(batch_size, caps1_n_caps, caps1_n_dims)`. And you need to combine them to produce `caps2_predicted` with shape `(batch_size, caps1_n_caps, caps1_n_dims, caps2_n_dims)`.

In the notebook they tile the tensors in order to operate them with [`tf.linalg.matmul`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul), but actually you can compute the same result without any tiling just using [`tf.einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 50
caps1_n_caps = 1152
caps1_n_dims = 8
caps2_n_caps = 10
caps2_n_dims = 16
w = tf.zeros((caps1_n_caps, caps2_n_caps, caps2_n_dims, caps1_n_dims), dtype=tf.float32)
caps1_output = tf.zeros((batch_size, caps1_n_caps, caps1_n_dims), dtype=tf.float32)
caps2_predicted = tf.einsum('ijkl,bil->bilk', w, caps1_output)
print(caps2_predicted.shape)
# (50, 1152, 8, 16)
```

---

I'm not sure if I have understood exactly what you want, but you say you want to compute something like:

*û*<sub>*ij*</sub> = *W*<sub>*ij*</sub> × *u*<sub>*i*</sub>

For a collection of several matrices *W* and vectors *u*. Assuming you have 900 matrices and vectors, matrices have size 20×20 and vectors have size 20, you can represent them as two tensors, `ws`, with shape `(900, 20, 20)`, and `us`, with shape `(900, 20)`. If you do that, you result `us_hat`, with shape `(900, 20, 20)`, would be computed simply as:

```py
us_hat = ws * tf.expand_dims(us, axis=-1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry to make you confused. The result u_hat has shape (900, 20, 1) or (900, 20) . That is the reason why I can not use the element-wise multiply. The tutorial I'm referring now is "https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/extra_capsnets.ipynb". ln[24].

Comment: matmul(wgt: [180 30 8 8], u:[180 30 8 1]) -> u_hat: [180 30 8 1]. (I removed the batch dimension)

Comment: I was impressed by the detailed explanation.Thank you very much. I did not use the einsum intentionally since I expected einsum uses tf.tile and tf.matmul automatically. I confirmed it works. There is a small one more question. there is a very small difference between einsum and tiling & matmul combination. The gap is about 1e-06. Is it a normal phenomenon?

Comment: also the implementation using einsum requires much smaller memory.

Comment: @KyungminLee About the difference in the result, it depends, float32 has around seven significant digits, so if the scale of your values is in the range of units or tens, or larger, then it's normal to see those imprecisions. If the values are in the scale of, say, 10^-4, then those errors would be much larger in relative terms, which should not be happening.

Comment: @jehesa, I'm really appreciated and satisfied with your answer! Thank you again!!